# What is replacement of box-orient with the new flexbox?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, flexbox

As per the Google guy's comment [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16854#issuecomment-524478266)

> box-orient (and its webkit variant) is a non-standard property left over from an old version of the flexbox spec. Any bugs with it are probably related to that.

So in the below code I want to remove the following styles `display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;`

and replace them with new flexbox specs, how can I do that the desired result is to clamp lines at 2 lines length as in the demo (text-overflow to ellipsis)

```html
<div style="min-height: 128px;
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(210, 210, 210, 0.5);
    border: solid 0.3px rgba(26, 25, 25, 0.15);
    background-color: #ffffff;
    width: 268px;
    margin-bottom: 13px;">

  <div style="overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    padding-top: 5.6px;
    display: -webkit-box;
    -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;">
    Can we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’? Can we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’? Can we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’? Can we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’? Can we make
    this upper case? and also remove the word and’? Can we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’?

  </div>

</div>
```

**Note:** The reason for this change is that this style doesn't work when the html element is hidden at default as mentioned in this [Github issue](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/16854). Working Angular Demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evutzr)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By examining and inspecting your StackBlitz demo. It seems like it is just an issue of view update. which can be resolved using `setTimeout()` function.

I have made some changes in your StackBlitz code and solved the issue. Here is the link: 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/sidenav-content-clamp-issue

I have used the `openedStart` event of `MatDrawer` and I am updating the content of side-bar inside event handler which has somehow solved the issue.

As I said earlier that it seems to be an update issue. So instead of assigning the content dynamically, we can also populate the `.text` class dynamically which will resolve the issue too.

Here is the code for .ts nad .html files.

**Template File**

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container" *ngIf="shouldRun">
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" [(opened)]="opened" (openedStart)="onSidebarOpenedChanged()" (closed)="events.push('close!')">
        Sidenav content

        <div class="container">
            <div class="text">
                {{content}} <!-- update this content in openedStart event handler-->
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-sidenav>

    <mat-sidenav-content>
        <p>
            <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="opened">sidenav.opened</mat-checkbox>
        </p>
        <!-- <p><button mat-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()">sidenav.toggle()</button></p> -->

        <div>SideNav should look the same</div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="text">
                {{longStr}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**Component File**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

/** @title Sidenav open & close behavior */
@Component({
  selector: 'sidenav-open-close-example',
  templateUrl: 'sidenav-open-close-example.html',
  styleUrls: ['sidenav-open-close-example.css'],
})
export class SidenavOpenCloseExample {
  events: string[] = [];
  opened: boolean;
  longStr = `Can we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’? Can we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’? Can
                we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’? Can we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’? Can
                we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’? Can we make this upper case? and also remove the word and’?`
  content;
  shouldRun = [/(^|\.)plnkr\.co$/, /(^|\.)stackblitz\.io$/].some(h => h.test(window.location.host));

  onSidebarOpenedChanged() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.content = this.longStr;
    });
  }
}
```

I also tried to find the replacement for box-orient but didn't find one and made this work around. I hope this will help.

Comment: This doesn't work if you open the side nav too fast https://imgur.com/a/CxilRzv I think If you open the sidenav before setTimeout is executed it will fail

Comment: what do you mean by "open side nav too fast"? do you mean clicking on toggle button quickly for multiple times ?

Comment: If you click it as soon as it finishes loading weird it works randomly

Answer (score 2):

In your angular code example, if you open the side nav, and toggle the div css display property twice in dev tools, it then works as expected. You can then open and close it with not problem.

Try to  render the div inside the side nav only when it is first opened.

Comment: Can you add a stackblitz example so that I can properly understand what you are conveying ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience in Angular. Just try to render the div inside the side nav after opening it for the first time, or only when it in state open.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a `line-height` on the inner `div`, and then set the `max-height` to twice the line height:

```css
line-height: 1.2em
max-height: 2.4em
```

Per MDN, [the default value of `normal` for `line-height` is around 1.2em but changes depending on the font](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height#Values).

Note: This will not allow the text to ellipsis

Comment: This will not work for me as Tex-overflow ellipsis is required

Comment: Maybe try some of the techniques here: https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Comment: Thats how I found line clamp at the first place

Answer (score 0):

Apply this css property to your div.

```
text-orientation: "either mixed or upright or sideways" ;
```

Comment: I thought you were trolling  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-orientation